# Use IF-ELSE clause inside a VIEW

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have to use the same view for all my users but i want to return different rows for different roles.

The structure should be like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_grades AS
IF test_special_role() 
THEN SELECT * FROM "Grades" 
ELSE SELECT * FROM "Grades" WHERE uid=get_current_uid() ...
END IF;
```

The function test_special_role() returns a boolean which is 'true' for the role 'Pam' and false otherwise. The function get_current_uid() returns the id of the current user (such a surprise :D ).

I also tried to use 'CASE' instead of 'IF' but that didn't help much. Maybe i should use 'CASE' inside the 'WHERE' statement, but what would i do in the 'true' case (WHERE ...nothing...)?

Database: PSQL 10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `IF` in SQL, but you can use a conditional WHERE clause:

```
CREATE VIEW view_grades AS
SELECT * 
FROM "Grades" 
WHERE (test_special_role() OR uid=get_current_uid());
```

But the better solution would be to use [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html) to limit access to the `"Grades"` table.

Comment: Of course you are right. I should try row level security. Thanks for the fast answer and i go bang my head to the wall now ... :D